# json.parse skipping values in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am getting a AJAX webcall with a formatted JSON text payload (Example A below). In the success function of the AJAX call, I run JSON.parse on the data payload as so:

```
var jsonified = JSON.parse( data.d );
```

Here's the problem. Sometimes, JSON.parse skips values that are present in data.d, as they go missing in var jsonified. For example, data.d has 30 fields per row, while jsonified will occasionally have 17 fields per row, and in a couple of rows, 20.

I can't figure out where the problem is going wrong. Occasionally, the var jsonified has the correct number of fields per row, but it'll usually revert back to the shortened versions without me making any code changes. I've tried parsing through jQuery function, which worked for a few passes, then reverted to exactly the same problem. Anyone come across this problem before? data.d and jsonified examples below.

data.d (only showing one row):

```
{"DATA":[["","SRRMAP","BTM",2015,"Lenscrafters","Name, Last","Name, Last","Name, Last",0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,0.00,"AIRFARE",0.00,0.00,291.84,11.50,11.00,422.70,17.00,50.00,5.50,5.50,0.00,0.00],null]}
```

One row from jsonified array:

```
0: ""
1: "SRRMAP"
2: "BTM"
3: 2015
4: "Lenscrafters"
5: "Name, Last"
6: "Name, Last"
7: "Name, Last"
8: 0
9: 0
10: 0
11: 0
12: 0
13: 5.5
14: 0
15: 0
```

Comment: [I can't replicate it](https://jsfiddle.net/9wdhof87/). I'm getting 29 entries. Are you sure you're always getting the same data through?

Comment: Are you using a GET request? It's possible that the browser is cacheing the response and not giving you fresh data every time.

Comment: I'm using a POST request as I need to pass in data values, but I hardcoded those values in for testing purposes. I occasionally got 29 entries, when I changed to jQuery's jSON.parse, but after a few calls, it reverted back, and then I'd revert back to Javascript's JSON.parse, only for it to work for a few calls but revert yet again. I did a few other things that I can't remember now, but it always reverted back to getting 15 entries. I can verify the raw data is always the same as 1st thing I do is console.log the raw text it to compare before manipulating and console.logging that too.